# Php how to parse Json

Tags: php, json

I am new in PHP can anyone please help me to parse JSON in php.

here is my data. I want to get status which is present under 'transaction_details' array.

```
Array (
    [status] => 1
    [msg] => 1 out of 1 Transactions Fetched Successfully
    [transaction_details] => Array (
        [3685189ee69337520311]   => Array (
            [mihpayid]           => 403993715516628289
            [request_id]         => 
            [bank_ref_num]       => 3808401291372621
            [amt]                => 51000.00
            [transaction_amount] => 51000.00
            [txnid]              => 3685189ee69337520311
            [additional_charges] => 0.00
            [productinfo]        => OasisEstate
            [firstname]          => Test
            [bankcode]           => CC
            [udf1]               => 
            [udf3]               => 
            [udf4]               => 
            [udf5]               => 
            [field9]             => SUCCESS
            [error_code]         => E000
            [card_type]          => VISA
            [error_Message]      => NO ERROR
            [net_amount_debit]   => 51000
            [disc]               => 0.00
            [mode]               => CC
            [PG_TYPE]            => HDFCPG
            [card_no]            => 401200XXXXXX1112
            [name_on_card]       => Neeraj
            [udf2]               => 
            [addedon]            => 2017-09-19 13:23:58
            [status]             => success
            [unmappedstatus]     => captured
            [Merchant_UTR]       => 
            [Settled_At]         => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        )
    )
)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you need to pass this array to json or to get a value from it?

Comment: You can just use any loop for getting the detail from the array.

Comment: please clarify, this is not json, neither is it the var_export of php (no comma)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to find the problem? Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

> echo $array['transaction_details'][3685189ee69337520311]['status']

Comment: In fact, $array['transaction_details']['status'] is undefined

Answer (score 1):

you don't need json when you already have an array

just use `$array['transaction_details']`

Comment: $array['status'] is a string, not an array

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your dump comes from a var $json:

```
<?php
foreach($json['transaction_details'] as $key => $details) {
   echo 'status for ' . $key .': ' . $details['status'];

}
?>
```

I used the foreach to overcome the problem of not knowing the key of the array. As I suppose the key will be different for every received json message

Answer (score 0):

array_pop() may help

```
$item = array_pop($array['transaction_details']); 
echo $item['status'];
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17376220)

Comment: Your answer was flagged by the Community as low quality (note it was added "From Review"). You state in that "array_pop() *may* help" - therefore this is a suggestion rather than a full and complete answer. If you have a reason to believe this would work, please edit your answer to explain why - code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question.  Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: you make me laugh, ha ha ha

Comment: Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).